# Google Chrome got weird after last Debian 12 update

Tags: chrome, software-updates

I installed Chrome on my new Lenovo Xiaoxin Pro laptop with Debian 12 KDE a month ago and all worked fine until recent update to 6.1.0-11 kernel.

1. Browser window is now scaled up with very big top controls and content area. It is quite inconvenient since I have to open multiple windows on my screen (I'm a programmer).

   Fortunately, I can adjust the browser content area scale manually to 75% every browser session while address bar with icons along it and bookmarks panel can not be set to normal size (I do not want to scale down browser top controls via overall system settings).
2. Browser window freezes and does not respond any more when docked to the edge of the monitor. The only remedy is to close the application via Debian taskbar.

Debian 12 is also installed on my desktop computer. It didn't prompt me for a kernel update (it remains at 6.1.0-9). I have no problems with top controls of the browser and docking freezing.

By the way, Firefox works like a charm. There are no undesired changes in it.

Did anybody face the same problem?
It looks like Debian's system issue.
I updated Chrome once after the kernel upgrade but problem persists.

---

These are updated packages

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-ldb.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-samba.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/smbclient.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libldb2:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/samba-dsdb-modules:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/samba-common-bin.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libsmbclient:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/samba-libs:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libwbclient0:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/samba-common.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-compiler-gcc-12-x86.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-headers-6.1.0-11-common.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-kbuild-6.1.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-headers-6.1.0-11-amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-headers-amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-6.1.0-11-amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-libc-dev:amd64.list
```

Comment: I can't imagine a kernel update would cause point 1 especially, but even point 2 seems unlikely  - perhaps *something else* updated - there's possibly a better way to  see this, but I always use the output of `ls -lrtc /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list` to see what's been updated most recently (newest packages at the end)

Comment: Jaromonada X, thank you for your reply. I added list of updated packages to my topic.

Answer (score 0):

Hallelujah!
Browser appearance restored with the latest update to 116.0.5845.140 version.
As for the second problem, browser window now freezes only when docked to the left edge of the laptop screen. Docking to the other 3 edges do not leed to freezing.